# Why when copying and pasting from website to Excel instead of the contents I get [object Object]?

Tags: copy, paste

I take data from a website and sort through it on Excel. Out of 10 columns pasted on Excel, 1 column gets pasted as [object Object] instead of its contents.  You can see a picture of copied vs pasted:
[Excel pasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diF96.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsRAO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.